# Chromium WebView does not exist

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am trying to create a Hello World app using Phonegap but it crashes when I call run the application on emulator. I followed the guideline [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide).  Here is what I have on MainActivity.java :

```
  package com.example.hello;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class HelloWorld extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.example.hello" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="HelloWorld" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
</manifest>
```

Here is the first errors I get :

1. Chromium WebView does not exist
2. FATAL EXCEPTION: main
3. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
   ComponentInfo{com.example.deneme/com.example.deneme.MainActivity}:
   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Can you tell me what is wrong with the application? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't `DroidGap` deprecated? Also are you correctly creating the phonegap project? When I say correctly I mean like described [**here**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide).

Comment: @XaverKapeller I was following an obsolete guideline, thanks for the link..

Comment: @XaverKapeller I  have created phonegap exactly described in the link. I still get the same errors..

Comment: Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/25003504/2164198

Comment: Have you tried to launch app on a read device?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, not every Android phone ships with Chromium as WebView engine (https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview). For instance, my Samsung Galaxy Ace2 with Android 4.1.2 has old WebView engine. User agent string denotes some unknown Mozilla version, HTML5 apps look&feel and behavior differs from Chrome. However, PhoneGap apps do not raise errors on my phone.

I don't know why you're getting "Chromium WebView does not exist" error, but since you're on the very beginnig on your way (cause you're trying to build Hello World app using Phonegap) I want to point to another option. Using [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org) project allows you not to deal with various WebView engines on every android device but use embedded in your app chromium engine - always the same on every android device. The crosswalk project is available for android and tizen platforms. So to build crossplatform app (android an iOS) I would suggest to use either

- [Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools), which can use single html5 source code with XDK api and Cordova api, that can be compiled to android app using crosswalk or compiled to iOS using native WebView.
- [Crosswalk+Cordova](https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/cordova) to build android app and PhoneGap to build iOS app from the same sources

This approach can eliminate pain on supporting various android devices.

See also:

http://html5hub.com/building-cordova-applications-with-crosswalk/

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/IxSuRUScbMs