# Running PhoneGap app in android

Tags: cordova

I am a newby to PhoneGap Development. I have installed phonegap into my system and I am tryig to run the test applicaation(**Hello World application**) in android emulator. Everything goes fine, I got **Build Successful** message and it was using emulator(**emulator-5554**) and I got **Launch Success** message also in my terminal but when I check in emulator I cannot see my app instead of it is displaying **Unfortunately HeeloWorld Application has stopped**.

Can anyone please guide me why this came and why my application is not showing in emulator.

**Update**

```
This is output from my logcat:

09-15 04:58:30.010: D/dalvikvm(1057): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
09-15 04:58:30.530: I/CordovaLog(1057): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
09-15 04:58:30.530: I/CordovaLog(1057): Found start page location: index.html
09-15 04:58:30.530: D/Whitelist(1057): Unlimited access to network resources
09-15 04:58:30.530: D/CordovaActivity(1057): CordovaActivity.onCreate()
09-15 04:58:31.020: E/WebViewFactory(1057): Chromium WebView does not exist
09-15 04:58:31.040: E/WebViewFactory(1057): Chromium WebView does not exist
09-15 04:58:31.040: D/AndroidRuntime(1057): Shutting down VM
09-15 04:58:31.040: W/dalvikvm(1057): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a7dd70)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): Process: com.example.hello, PID: 1057
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hello/com.example.hello.HelloWorld}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at com.android.webview.nullwebview.NullWebViewFactoryProvider.createWebView(NullWebViewFactoryProvider.java:41)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2058)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2116)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3461)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3517)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:498)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:475)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:455)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:444)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:434)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.<init>(CordovaWebView.java:137)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebView(CordovaActivity.java:272)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:307)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at com.example.hello.HelloWorld.onCreate(HelloWorld.java:31)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
09-15 04:58:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Include the stack trace (from logcat) of the crash.

Comment: Actually that's the build output/console.  Press `Alt-6` (Android Studio) to show the logcat.

Comment: @mstrthealias I have added logcat. could you please check once

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chromium WebView does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019784/chromium-webview-does-not-exist)

Comment: Not sure why your emulator doesn't have Chromium, but maybe try using a *Google APIs* emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem by changing Target of AVD as `Android 4.4.2 API Level 19` then it worked fine now.

Hope this may help someone

Comment: Yes, Chrome is the default WebView only from Android 4.4 onwards:
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html